# What is the most efficient way to do comparisons involving many-many relationships with LINQ in EF 4.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my database I have the following tables:

- Person
- Post
- InterestTag

Many-Many relationships exist between Person-InterestTag and Post-InterestTag

I need to perform a linq query in EF 4.1 to pull back any post that contains at least one interest tag that matches at least one interest tag related to the given user.

**Example**

A person has the following interests:

- Cars
- Sports
- Fitness

I need to return any Post that is related to either cars, sports, or fitness.

What is the most efficient way to write this query in terms of performance?

**Edit**

Running into an error based on the answer given below...

This compiles fine but throws an error at runtime:

```
var matchingPosts = posts.Where(post => post.Topics.Any(postTopic =>   person.Interests.Contains(postTopic)));
```

The error is:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT 2**

So my classes are structured as such:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    //other properties of types string, int, DateTime, etc.

    public ICollection<InterestTag> InterestTags {get; set;}      
}


public class Post
{
    public int PostID {get; set;}
    public string Title{get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}
    //other properties of types string, int, DateTime, etc.

    public ICollection<InterestTag> InterestTags {get; set;}


}

public class InterestTag
{
    public int InterestTagID { get; set; }
    public string InterestDescription { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

In my Context class I am overriding OnModelCreating to define my DB table names

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(u => u.InterestTags).WithMany(t => t.Persons)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("PersonID");
        m.MapRightKey("InterestTagID");
        m.ToTable("PersonInterestTags");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(u => u.InterestTags).WithMany(t => t.Posts)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("PostID");
        m.MapRightKey("InterestTagID");
        m.ToTable("PostInterestTags");
    });
```

In my query method I am bring back an IQueryable of Post and applying some filters, including the clause in which I am trying to accomplish in this question.

```
 var person = personRepository.Get(x => x.PersonID = 5);
 var posts = postRepository.GetQueryable();

 //I have tried this and get the error above
 posts= posts.Where(x => x.InterestTags.Any(tag => person.InterestTags.Contains(tag)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with just a given `personId` (or `userId`) you can do this query in one roundtrip like so:

```
var posts = context.Posts
    .Intersect(context.People
        .Where(p => p.Id == givenPersonId)
        .SelectMany(p => p.InterestTags.SelectMany(t => t.Posts)))
    .ToList();
```

This translates into an `INTERSECT` statement in SQL.

You can also do this in two roundtrips:

```
var interestTagsOfPerson = context.People.Where(p => p.Id == givenPersonId)
    .Select(p => p.InterestTags.Select(t => t.Id))
    .SingleOrDefault();
// Result is an IEnumerable<int> which contains the Id of the tags of this person

var posts = context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.InterestTags.Any(t => interestTagsOfPerson.Contains(t.Id)))
    .ToList();
// Contains translates into an IN clause in SQL
```

Using a list of primitive types in the second query (`interestTagsOfPerson` is a collection of `int`) also fixes the error you mentioned in your Edit in the question. For `Contains` you cannot use object references in LINQ to Entities because EF doesn't know how to translate that into SQL.

I have no clue which of the two approaches is faster (SQL experts might have a better idea) but would probably start to test the first option. (I've tested a little bit and it seemed to return the correct results, but it's the first time that I have used `Intersect`.)

**Edit**

To give an idea of the generated SQL (captured from SQL Profiler):

The first query (with `Intersect`) creates this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
[Intersect1].[Id] AS [C1], 
[Intersect1].[Name] AS [C2], 
FROM  (SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
INTERSECT
    SELECT 
    [Join1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Join1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    FROM  [dbo].[PersonInterestTags] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN (SELECT [Extent3].[TagId] AS [TagId],
                           [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id],
                           [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name]
                    FROM  [dbo].[PostInterestTags] AS [Extent3]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent4]
                        ON [Extent3].[PostId] = [Extent4].[Id] ) AS [Join1]
            ON [Extent2].[TagId] = [Join1].[TagId]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent2].[PersonId]) AS [Intersect1]
```

The second option:

Query1 (for the list of the person's tag Ids):

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[TagId] AS [TagId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[TagId] AS [TagId], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[PersonId] IS NULL)
                 THEN CAST(NULL AS int)
                 ELSE 1
             END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
        FROM [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id] ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PersonInterestTags] AS [Extent2]
            ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PersonId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Query 2 for the final posts:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[PostInterestTags] AS [Extent2]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PostId]) AND ([Extent2].[TagId] IN (1,2,3))
)
```

In this example the query 1 returned (1,2,3), hence the (1,2,3) in the `IN` clause in query 2.

Comment: I am trying to adapt your answer to my scenario but I am still getting the same error as specified in my original question. Please see my second edit for a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to do. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: @stephen776: The model I tested looked exactly like yours (aside from slightly different property names) and it worked. Which of the two version in my answer did you try? Do you really get this "Unable to create a constant value..." exception? I cannot see how this could occur in my examples. Can you perhaps show the code you are exactly testing?

Comment: the query I am tryin is: posts = posts.Where(x => x.InterestTags.Any(tag => person.InterestTags.Select(ut => ut.InterestTagID).Contains(tag.InterestTagID)));...where posts is an Iqueryable and person is a person object from the repository

Comment: @stephen776: Did you load `person.InterestTags` with `Include` in your repository? What exception do you get?

Comment: @stephen776: Just as a warning because you were asking for efficiency: When you load the complete `Person` object with its `Tag` collection with `Include` you load more into memory than you really need to finally get the posts. To avoid this the second solution above only loads the tag Ids and the first just needs `person.PersonID`. Following those approaches you would not need `Include`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I had to edit my post because I forgot about the many-many-relationship between post and topic. Now it should work.

I cannot tell you if this is the most efficient way, but it would be a way using LINQ queries so it should be highly efficient:

```
var matchingPosts = posts.Where(post => post.Topics.Any(postTopic => person.Interests.Contains(postTopic)));
```

If you want to use parallel execution you could modify it like that:

```
var matchingPosts = posts.AsParallel().Where(post => post.Topics.Any(postTopic => person.Interests.Contains(postTopic)));
```

As you are using EF you would need this query:

```
var matchingPosts = from post in posts
    where post.Topics.Any(topic => person.Interests.Contains(topic))
    select post;
```

Comment: unfortunately, when using this query(first example above), I am getting the following error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this error. Could you provide the structure of the classes you are using? Especially the types of the class members would be interesting.

Comment: I have added some more info about my classes and query above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

how about this:

```
context.Persons
       .Where(p => p.Name == "x")
       .SelectMany(p => p.Interests.SelectMany(i => i.Posts))
       .Distinct()
       .Take(10)
       .ToList();
```

Take() is there for performance reasons and pagination. You should never select all records because first of all no user will read a list of thousands records and second the result set could grow in the future and the query will not scale.