# Showing SQL command with EF4.1's ToString()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an EF4.1 database first application, and the .ToString() method is only giving me the reflected type, [and not the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016773/how-do-i-use-linq-and-entity-framework-to-join-two-jointables/8016921#8016921).

How do I make my application show me the Linq query in SQL format?

I've added version 4.1 of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1\Binaries\EntityFramework.dll` to my project.  I'm guessing the ToString feature is added by an extension method, but even when I add "Using system.data.Entity" I'm unable to getthe string output to work.

> Does this mean ToString only works for Code First deployments?

```
  public IEnumerable<CompanyDetail> GetAllCompanies(int? startPage, int? stopPage, string Filter, int? MaxResults)
    {
        var t = from c in _entities.CompanyDetail
                select c;

        string test = t.ToString();

        var t2 = _entities.CompanyDetail;

        string test2 = t2.ToString();
        return t.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that it works for database first applications.

I am guessing your code is still using the EF 4 classes since you didn't mention adding the EF 4.1 DbContext generator to your model.  If that's the case, you can right-click on the model, choose "Add Code Generation Item..." and select the ADO.NET C# DbContext Generator.  If you don't see it in your installed templates, look for it under Online Templates.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what I would do without S.O. I spent hours looking for this in VS and online. Much appreciation man

Comment: Seems like there may be a bug in EF4.1, possibly a reflection issue  (or implementation issue) with Appfabric caching http://stackoverflow.com/q/8131195/328397   ... in case you want to know...