# EF4.1 hangs for 120 seconds when using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory

Tags: azure, entity-framework-4.1, azure-appfabric

I have a consistent, repeatable 120 second hang whenever the application calls

```
 this.cacheProvider.Add(new CacheItem(cacheKey, data, this.regionName), cachePolicy);
```

at line 60 of the [CachedDataSource.cs of the sample.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457899).  The `.Add` method is internal to Microsoft's DLL and I don't have code to it.  Here are my parameters:

```
cacheKey = "listofCompanies"
data = // this is an EF 4.0 database first model class with 70 entries... result from IQueryable
this.regionName = "companies"
```

**Reproducing the error:**

I have a database-first EF4.0 project that I recently upgraded to 4.1 by adding the "EntityFramework" reference and a [ContextGenerator to my DAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489).

If I undo these changes, then my application is instantly performant.

My DAL and repository are stored in a separate DLL from my MVC application.  Not sure if this is playing a part of the issue.

**About my repository**

```
    /// Sample repository.  Note that I return List<T> as IEnumerable, 
    /// and I use IDisposable 
    ///
    public class CompanyRepository : DisposableBase, ICompanyRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<CompanyDetail> GetOneCompany(int? CompanyID)
        {
            var t = from c in _entities.CompanyDetail
                    where c.CompanyID == CompanyID.Value
                    select c;
            return t.ToList();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposable implementation based on advice from this link:
    /// from Http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
    /// </summary>
    public class DisposableBase : IDisposable
    {
        protected TLSAdminEntities1 _entities;

        public DisposableBase()
        {
            _entities = new TLSAdminEntities1();
            disposed = false;
        }

        private bool disposed ;
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _entities.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**Question**

Is this a bug, or am I using EF4.1, or the Caching layer incorrectly?

Comment: Provider the real code where the problem occurs.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka the real code is the CachedDataSourceSample.. it's part of the SDK.  To add the designer I'd have to upload a project.  where should I put such a project?

Comment: I don't say you should provide the whole source code but some code snippet related to the issue. Nobody will go to download any specific SDK or sample to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka  I'll have to think about what to share to explain my issue.  The issue is within the internals of the MSFT AppFabric cache.   I call it with the same parameters, but simply put, if the ContextGenerator is present then the .Add method is 120 seconds long.  If I remove EF 4.1, .Add() takes less than 1 second.

Comment: In such case compare database activity, implementation of entity or use some profiler to see what's happening in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that data is the result of IQueryable.  Have you tried to perform .ToList() first on the data before sending it over to cache?

Comment: I do use `.ToList()`.  The MSFT cache requires that all data be serializable, and IQuerable<T> doesn't appear to be.  I added a sample repository